# d3.nest().key().map().each is not a function

Tags: d3.js

I'm using D3 v4.  I've searched far and wide for this but found nothing.  I reproduced the problem at [Mister Nester](http://bl.ocks.org/shancarter/raw/4748131/) but someone pointed out that Mr. N is using D3 v3.  Still, the data set and code example they use will still create 'my' error if used with D3 v4.

Here's the code to paste in:

```
d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.year; })
  .map(data).each(function(values, key) { return 0;});
```

The browser console catches the error about

> "not a function": Uncaught TypeError:
>   d3.nest(...).key(...).map(...).each is not a function

---

If you search through the [unminified v4 code](https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js) you will find an example of `map.each` used exactly as I've used it:

```
map.each(function(v, k) { array.push({key: k, values: entries(v, depth)});
```

Then the code that defines `map.each` says the same thing:

```
each: function(f) {
    for (var property in this) if (property[0] === prefix) f(this[property], property.slice(1), this);
  }
```

This is my first stackoverflow question.  I tried to be thorough.  Please let me know if I should do things differently.

Answer (score 1):

The `Mister Nester` tool you link to is running d3 **version 3**.  From the version 3 docs:

> nest.map(array[, mapType])
>
> Applies the nest operator to the specified array, returning an
>   associative array.

That's a plain old javascript object, which does not have a `.each` method.

The closest to what you want in version 3 is:

```
 d3.nest()
   .key(function(d) { return d.year; })
   .map(data, d3.map)
   .forEach(function(values, key) { return 0;});
```

Comment: I'm using v4.  Do you have any advice for that?  Thanks.

Comment: @boopbeepboop, for me to help further, you'll need to reproduce the error with version 4.  I've tried with "Mister Lister's" data and d3 version 4 [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XpgYpPcZs751tElSO5Cm?p=preview) and see no issues.